# How to Implement EditText in ListView like a Tree view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am working with android development and want to implement edittext in listview such like that in picture[image: imagr]. now want to add this kind of implementation. is there any way to do exactly this thing or any library which  is doing this work.any kind of help will be appreciated and thanks an advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. I recommend you not to use listview to implement that. Just use LinearLayout with vertical orientation, and add each field when the "Add More" button item clicked.

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout); //make sure you have set vertical orientation attribute on your xml

TextView addMoreText = new TextView(context);
addMoreText.setText("Add More");
addMoreText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         EditText editTextItem = new EditText(context); 
         parentLayout.addView(editTextItem, 0);
      }
});

parentLayout.addView(addMoreText);
```

Note that the code above is just global picture of how to solve your problem. For implementation with close or add button on the right side, you may create custom view that holds EditText, ImageView based your own.